# os.rename is adding an extra character when renaming to something with a utf character

Tags: python-3.x, windows, filenames, utf, iso-8859-1

This is the first time I've asked a question on stackoverflow so let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

I'm trying to rename a file with the os library. I want the file name to include some non-ascii characters that are in a string that I've generated. Here's the code:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(startDir):
    for file in files:
        # some code to generate the newFileName string

        os.rename(os.path.join(subdir,file), s.path.join(subdir,newFileName))
```

Here's an example of what the newFileName string would be: "te©st©.txt"

However when the file saves, it adds in an extra character: "teÂ©stÂ©.txt"

From other reading I've done it sounds like utf-8 actually maps certain codes to two characters, or something like that, and that's where the Â is coming from. If I print the string right before calling os.rename, it prints to the terminal the way that I would expect it to. So I'm guessing it must be something with the way that os.rename is interaction with the filesystem.

I am using Windows.

Comment: Show the output of `print(ascii(newFileName))`.

Comment: 'te\xc2\xa9st\xc2\xa9.txt'

Comment: If it's `str` (text), the ASCII repr should be `'te\xa9st\xa9.txt'`. If it's UTF-8 encoded `bytes`, the ASCII repr should be `b'te\xc2\xa9st\xc2\xa9.txt'`. What you actually have appears to be UTF-8 decoded as Latin-1 or Windows codepage 1252. Make sure your source file is encoded as UTF-8 and use exactly `newFileName = "te©st©.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try using unicode all the way?

```
path = u'99 bottles of \N{greek small letter beta}eer on the wall.txt'
f = open(path, 'w')
f.write('Hello, World!\n')
f.close()
import glob
print(glob.glob(path)) # ['99 bottles of βeer on the wall.txt']
import os
print(os.path.getsize(path)) # 15
```